# knapsack with variety of items

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

Suppose a regular knapsack problem: you have a weight constraint, `C`, the number of items with `Value` and `Weight` `(V, W)`. You want to maximize the `V` while `W` being under the `C`. In this question, you can only have one of each item.

But there is an additional twist to the problem. You want to have a variety of items. Suppose the question states that you want to have at least 5 (or any number) of different items. If a solution has any less than 5 different items, the answer is not valid. Is there an approach to this problem that solves this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just another form of constraint, so lets see how Weight (at most C weight) and Diversity (at least 5 different items) differ:

- Weight starts as a valid (empty bag is below C), while Diversity starts as invalid (empty bag doesn't contain 5 different items).

The first thing to note is, that with the additional constraint you need a notion of invalid / unsolvable, because if there aren't 5 different items that satisfy the weight constraint, there is no solution.

Once you defined a way to return some `invalid` result, it's really close to the standard knapsack problem. In recursion, just pass remaining allowed Weight and current Diversity. In the recursion anchor case, check Diversity and return `invalid` if Diversity does not meet requirements, otherwise return the result like in the normal knapsack problem. Check recursion results for `invalid` and treat it accordingly.